# Pip package a django project

Tags: django, python-3.x, pip, setuptools

The target is to create a pip package of a Django project.

The goal is to make the web application quickly installable anywhere just by doing `pip install`.

The use cases are 2 that I can think of:

1. Manually start the application using a console_scripts like `client-web-up` that should be the equivalent to type `manage.py runserver`. 
   This is what I'm focused on right now.
2. create some sort of script to generate configuration files for apache, nginx etc... for later.

#### Steps taken

- Created a main folder `client_web` for my pip package.
- Moved all my project into `client_web` folder.
- Created a setup.py as shown below.
- Edited manage.py file so its content can be executed by an function named `entry()`.
- Publish the pip package which downloads and installs correctly.

  ```
  from setuptools import setup

  setup(
    name="client-web",
    ...,
    version="2018.08.03.3",
    packages=[
      "client_web",
      "client_web.controller",
      "client_web.measurement",
      "client_web.webapp",
      "client_web.controller.migrations",
      "client_web.measurement.migrations",
    ],
    include_package_data=True,
    install_requires=[
      ...
    ],
    entry_points={
      "console_scripts": [
        "client-web-up=client_web.manage:entry"
      ]
    }
  )
  ```

#### The problem

If i type the following in the terminal:

```
$ client-web-up

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/client-web-up", line 26, in <module>
    sys.exit(entry())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/client_web/manage.py", line 33, in entry
    main();
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/client_web/manage.py", line 30, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 352, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 89, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 116, in create
    mod = import_module(mod_path)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'webapp'
```

But if I do:

```
$ pip3 show client-web

  Name: client-web
  Version: 2018.8.3.3
  Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages
  Requires: ...
  Required-by: ...

$ python3 /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/client_web/manage.py 

  Available subcommands:

  [auth]
      changepassword
      createsuperuser

  [contenttypes]
      remove_stale_contenttypes

  [django]
      ...
```

Could someone help me find a way to make the console_script work?

Comment: This sounds like a problem that would better be solved by something like Docker, to be honest.

Comment: We are using docker too actually. The point is that we would also like to distribute the app as a pip package.

Comment: Another reason why that is not the best approach is that I need to install this ns ARM machines and I either need to generate my docker image on an ARM, which is incredibly slow, or cross-compile on an x86 machine using a specific base image that is ~400Mb.

Comment: The error does not relate to the setup script. Please add a [mcve] of a Django project failing. Based on the stack trace and the packages list, you have issues with `sys.path` - importing `webapp` instead of `client_web.webapp` or similar.

Answer (score 2):

solved by adding a sys.path like so:

```
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
```